# Use Strict with Isotope Issue?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a custom js file, with a function for Isotope inside it. All is fine, until I declare Use Strict at the top, then I get an error -

In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function.

I have the following Isotope code, but unsure how I should adjust this for compliance?

```
if ($('.full-width').length) {

    function portfolioColumn() {
        var width = $(window).width(),
            column;

        if (width > 1400) {
            column = 4;
        } else if (width > 1000) {
            column = 3;
        } else if (width > 550) {
            column = 2;
        } else if (width > 0) {
            column = 1;
        }

        return column;
    }

    function setColumn() {
        if (!$('.portfolio-items').length) return false

        var width = $(window).width(),
            column = portfolioColumn(),
            articleWidth = Math.floor(width / column);

        $('.portfolio-items .project-item').each(function () {
            $(this).css({
                width: articleWidth + 'px'
            });
        });
    }

    setColumn();
    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        setColumn();
    });
};

$(window).load(function () {
    var $container = $('.portfolio-items');
    var $filter = $('.filter');
    // Initialize isotope 
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear'
        }
    });
    // Filter items when filter link is clicked
    $filter.find('a').click(function () {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $filter.find('a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                animationDuration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false,
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a function declaration within an `if` statement.

This is a restriction, because wheter it is declared in the `if` or not, the function is scoped to the top and usable.

Basically, you **cannot do conditionnal function declaration** (it simply doesn't work this way in JavaScript). To fix it, assign a function to a variable instead.

```
var portfolioColumn;

if ($('.full-width').length) {

    portfolioColumn = function () { /* etc */ };

}
```